# Expansion panels dynamic content loading

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a complex scenario where I need expansion panels to be able to load different components when expanded. All panels are collapsed by default when view is loaded. As soon a panel is clicked, I need to fetch data from server and place the result in the panel contents. So few challenges here:

1. How do I refer to the content of the expansion panel that were engaged when I have multiple panels?
2. How do I load dynamically components into that panel content? Components are vary from each other by the way and depend from the content that is loading, although I know which to render as the panel is rendered.

Comment: I am facing same problem, did you figure out the solution for this?

Comment: No, eventually this feature was abandoned. But while working on it, my plan was to use ViewChild for the panel in the TS script

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ComponentFactoryResolver` to dynamically load data. For that you can register event handler for `afterExpand` of [expansion panel](https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/api).
You have to make following changes.

**Template**

```
      <mat-expansion-panel (afterExpand)="expand()">
         <mat-expansion-panel-header>
           Header
         </mat-expansion-panel-header>
         <!--where component will be loaded-->
         <ng-template component></ng-template>
      </mat-expansion-panel>
```

**TS File**

```
      @ViewChild(Component, {static: true}) component: Component;
      constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) { }

      expand(){//method to load component when panel is expanded
           const componentFactory = 
          this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(Component);

          const viewContainerRef = this.component.viewContainerRef;
          viewContainerRef.clear();

          const componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
          // here you can send data to dynamically loaded component
         (<Component>componentRef.instance).data = component.data;
      }
```

Before passing data to component, you can fetch new response.